# How to open panes when creating widgets in Flutter slideable package

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

How to open panes while creating widgets in Flutter slideable package? I want to open and close the cards to inform the user that transactions can be made by swiping the card, how can I do this?

```
Slidable(
                          key: const ValueKey(0),
                          startActionPane: ActionPane(
                            motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                            dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {}),
                            children: [
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) {},
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                                label: 'Delete',
                              ),
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) {},
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF21B7CA),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.share,
                                label: 'Share',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          endActionPane: ActionPane(
                            motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                            children: [
                              SlidableAction(
                                flex: 2,
                                onPressed: (context) {},
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7BC043),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.archive,
                                label: 'Archive',
                              ),
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) {},
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0392CF),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.save,
                                label: 'Save',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: const ListTile(title: Text('Slide me')),
                        ),
```